# How to mark a compilation as failed and make webpack to exit with non-zero return value from a plugin?

Tags: plugins, error-handling, webpack, return-code

I'd like to create a webpack plugin that checks the codebase and optionally marks the compilation as failed and caused webpack (if not running in watch mode) to exit with non-zero return code.

I noticed that plugins can report errors like this:

```js
compilation.errors.push(new Error('foo error'))
```

However such errors doesn't cause non-zero return code. It seems that loaders (based on examination of `babel-loader`) can achieve that by mere throwing an exception.

**How to make webpack to exit with non-zero return code from its plugin?** Assuming that `bail` flag is set and one doesn't want to resort to hacks like:

```js
if (bail) {
    process.on('exit', () => process.exitCode = 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin can report a failure by passing an true-ish object to callback of `run` hook:

```js
compiler.plugin('run', (compiler, callback) => {
    callback(new Error('problem description'))
})
```

Code above causes webpack to exit with return code `1`.

This holds for all methods marked as *async* in [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/plugins.html#note-on-interface-types):

> async: Last parameter is a callback. Signature: function(err, result)

Comment: And what about synchronous hooks?